# Do Firefox and Chrome treat differently selections?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I‘m trying to get the caret on an element with `contenteditable="true"`, with a handler. In Firefox all works as expected and if I put the handler for an onclick event it works fine on Chrome as well. The problem arises when the handler is for an `onfocus` event of the contenteditable, which is what I want to do.

This is the code I'm using only to try to figure out why is this happening.

```js
var editor = document.querySelector("#editor [contenteditable]");
var blackboard = document.querySelector("textarea");

editor.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  blackboard.value = getSelection().focusNode.data;
  console.log(getSelection(), getSelection().focusNode);
})
```

```html
<div id="maq">
  <textarea rows="44" cols="50">
      </textarea>
</div>
<div id="editor">
  <div contenteditable="true">
    <p>11111</p>
    <p>2222</p>
    <p>3333<br></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

`getSelection` seems to return the expected object. If I inspect it in the browser console its `focusNode` is a nodeText in `contenteditable`; but if I try actually to use the focusNode it returns the object I was before going to the `contenteditable`. For example, if I click in some text in the navigation bar and then click in contenteditable, it returns the nodeText in the navigation bar.
Any idea why is this?
Thank you.

Comment: In case it's useful, MDN indicates a few caveats for `contentEditable` in this article
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content (and there is more information available via the links in the article's  'See Also' section: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content#See_also)

Answer (score 0):

`getSelection()` doesn't return a DomNode but a `Selection` object which, based on your results, I suspect is a *live* value, just like how `node.childNodes` is a `NodeList` which gets automatically updated if you add or remove children.
So when the selection changes you magically get the new selection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The weird thing abount this selection issue is that only happens in Chrome and when I use the focus event. When I substitute click for focus all works fine.

Comment: Such is life. Have you tried other browsers like Opera?

Comment: And then there is life in browsers world, which is a little worse :( Same problem on Opera as on Chrome.